# How to make action on keyboard input be instant

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I am writing in C++ and using OpenGL in Windows.
I've created a cube and I want it to be rotated around the y axis ( *using glRotate3f(), not gluLookat()* ) by pressing '4' or '6' numpad keys.
The problem is that when I press any key, there is a slight rotation and then stops for a while and then it starts rotating continuously.

Is there any way to achieve this by using glutkeyboardfunc?

If not, how can it be achieved?

Comment: I think that's in the keyboard. The key starts repeating when it has been pressed for a while.

Comment: Are are using a get key state or using keypress events?

Comment: "*by using glutkeyboardfunc only*" What exactly are you trying to do? Do you want continuous motion, or do you want to have the rotation step a bit every time the key is pressed? And why do you need it to be only using one function?

Comment: @BoPersson: There's should be a way to do that, as it is done in games (that's what I am aiming to accomplish).

Comment: @monkey: I am using this `glutKeyboardFunc()` to call a function with this declaration `void Keyboard(unsigned char key,int x,int y)` and using switch statement in this function to check which key is pressed. So is it a "get key state" ?

Comment: @NicolBolas: With "by using glutkeyboardfunc only" I meant not using a game engine that enables us this functionality (mayby the "only" was a bit off). I am trying to get continuous motion from the moment a key is pressed down as it is done in games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain your own key state map and trigger redraws on a timer:

```
// g++ main.cpp -o main -lglut -lGL -lGLU && ./main
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <map>

bool paused = false;
std::map< unsigned char, bool > state;
void keyboard_down( unsigned char key, int x, int y )
{
    if( key == 'p' )
        paused = !paused;

    state[ key ] = true;
}

void keyboard_up( unsigned char key, int x, int y )
{
    state[ key ] = false;
}

void display()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    double w = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH );
    double h = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT );
    double ar = w / h;
    glOrtho( -2 * ar, 2 * ar, -2, 2, -1, 1);

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    static float angle = 0;
    if( state[ '6' ] )  angle -= 3;
    if( state[ '4' ] )  angle += 3;
    if( !paused )
        angle += 0.5;

    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef( angle, 0, 0, 1 );

    glColor3ub( 255, 0, 0 );
    glBegin( GL_QUADS );
    glVertex2i( -1, -1 );
    glVertex2i(  1, -1 );
    glVertex2i(  1,  1 );
    glVertex2i( -1,  1 );
    glEnd();

    glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void timer( int extra )
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc( 16, timer, 0 );
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( 640, 480 );
    glutCreateWindow( "Keyboard" );
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutKeyboardFunc( keyboard_down );
    glutKeyboardUpFunc( keyboard_up );
    glutTimerFunc( 0, timer, 0 );
    glutIgnoreKeyRepeat( GL_TRUE );
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You say _... in stock GLUT because it doesn't have any way of notifying you of key-up events_, but that's precisely what `glutKeyboardUpFunc` does (which you're using).  That function has been in Mark Kilgard's GLUT since the beginning.

Comment: Thanks!  You're right, I was looking at old documentation.  Fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. The modifications I made was to include the check for a key down at the Idle function. Also, what is timer function used for?

Comment: The timer is there to trigger redraws since the keydown/keyup functions aren't.

Comment: And how is the timer called when the button is pressed (Since the timer function is only called into the timerfunc callback) ?

Comment: The key-up/down functions just set the key state.  GLUT itself calls `timer()` every 16ms or so, independent of the keyboard.

Comment: @genpfault: Thank you for the information. I needed to use the 'p' button as a pause action, but when I press it with your implementation, the pause function is called >= 2 times, depending on how long I press the button, how can I achieve this? Could I check at the keyboard_down function if the key == 'p', call pause function, and if not, so what you've posted?

Comment: @Chris: Edited.  Yep, adding a `p` check in `keyboard_down()` works.  Don't forget the `glutIgnoreKeyRepeat()` call in `main()`.

Comment: Thank you again for your comment, I have already implemented it as I've told you in the previous comment. I wouldn't need `glutIgnoreKeyRepeat()` because I am using the arrow keys to increase/ decrease some values. Thank you for suggesting it though.